# drag and drop an image from listbox

Tags: c#, wpf, drag-and-drop, listbox

I have a listbox with Images `<Image Source="{Binding Path=Image}" Width="56" Height="61"/>` and a drag and drop event. Is it possible to do such thing: when I drop selected item on rectangle, for example, the image from this item pops up on this rectangle?

```
              <WrapPanel
                   Name="WeaponPanel"  Style="{StaticResource Panel}">
            <ListBox x:Name="listweapons" Height="214" Width="248" ItemsSource="{Binding ListWeapon}"
         IsSynchronizedWithCurrentItem="True" Canvas.Left="211" Canvas.Top="72" 
        PreviewMouseLeftButtonDown="weapons_PreviewMouseLeftButtonDown" DragLeave="weapons_DragLeave"

        PreviewMouseMove="weapons_PreviewMouseMove" SelectedValuePath="attack">

                <ListBox.ItemTemplate >
                    <DataTemplate >
                        <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
                            <Image Source="{Binding Path=Image}" Width="56" Height="61"/>
                            <TextBox Height="30" Width="30">

                                    <Binding Path="_attack" />
                                 </TextBox>
                            </StackPanel>
                    </DataTemplate>
                </ListBox.ItemTemplate>
            </ListBox>
        </WrapPanel>
 private void helmet_MouseDown1(object sender, MouseButtonEventArgs e)
    {
        _startPoint = e.GetPosition(null);


    }

    private void helmet_PreviewMouseMove(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
    {
        Point mousePos = e.GetPosition(null);
        Vector diff = _startPoint - mousePos;
        if (e.LeftButton == MouseButtonState.Pressed &&
  (Math.Abs(diff.X) > SystemParameters.MinimumHorizontalDragDistance ||
  Math.Abs(diff.Y) > SystemParameters.MinimumVerticalDragDistance))
        {

            var listBox = sender as ListBox;
            var listBoxItem = listBox.SelectedItem;

            DataObject dragData = new DataObject(_dropIdentifier, listBoxItem);
            DragDrop.DoDragDrop(listBox, dragData, DragDropEffects.Move);
        }
  private void Rectangle_Drop_1(object sender, System.Windows.DragEventArgs e)
    {
        ((Rectangle)sender).Fill = new SolidColorBrush(Color.FromRgb(14, 14, 14));

   }
```

Comment: Can you please show more of your code? Also, am I understanding you correctly: You want to set things up so that if an image is dropped on to one of the items in your listbox the image that was dragged and dropped is shown in a pop up?

Comment: @OrenHizkiya I've updated my question. I mean, the same image that is contained in selected item in listbox - the image i'm dragging and dropping should appear on this rectangle, but it shouldn't be removed from listbox